# robin_stocks .get_crypto_quote TypeError

Tags: python

Writing a simple Robinhood bitcoin trading bot for practice. Keep getting TypeError in line 9.

```
import robin_stocks as rs
import time
   
global pp
rs.login(<username>, <password>)
bought = False
while True:
    time.sleep(15)
    btc = rs.crypto.get_crypto_quote('BTC')
    print(btc)
    print(btc['mark_price'])
    if not bought:
        rs.orders.order_buy_crypto_by_price('BTC', 10.00, 'mark_price')
        pp = float(btc['mark_price'])
        bought = True
    elif bought:
        if float(btc['mark_price']) >= (pp * 1.005):
            rs.orders.order_sell_crypto_by_price('BTC', 10.05, 'ask_price')
```

The Error I get is:

```
line 104, in <listcomp>
    data = [x for x in data if x['asset_currency']['code'] == symbol]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick search, I found a page sayign that you need to provide that line in the format `get_crypto_quotes()` --> meaning that you're missing an s. Let me know if this works. Here's the documentation I found:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/coinmarketcapr/versions/0.3/topics/get_crypto_quotes